# how to expand and collapase list

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3

The following is working fine. But its only working for the first instance of the revenue other instance are just showing the list without collapse or expand. As the user clicks on the revene.Amount it should expand and show revenue.Q1, revenue.Q2, revenue.Q3 and revenue.Q4. And by default everything should be collapsed.

```
<% @estate.revenues.each do |revenue| %>    
  <tr>
    <td><%= revenue.Year %></td>
    <div id="listContainer">
      <ul id="expList">
        <li>
          <%= revenue.Amount %>
          <ul>
            <li><%= revenue.Q1 %></li>
            <li><%= revenue.Q2 %></li>
            <li><%= revenue.Q3 %></li>
            <li><%= revenue.Q4 %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', estate_revenue_path(@estate,revenue), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_estate_revenue_path(@estate,revenue) %>
    <%= link_to 'View', estate_revenue_path(@estate,revenue) %>
    <br/>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<br />

<%= link_to 'New Revenue', new_estate_revenue_path(@estate.id) %>

<script>
    function prepareList() {
        $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
                .click( function(event) {
                    if (this == event.target) {
                        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
                        $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .addClass('collapsed')
                .children('ul').hide();
    };
    $(document).ready( function() {
        prepareList()
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is likely the issue here. Furthermore, I feel you are trying to do too much with your chaining. Please try the refactored version of your code below:

```
$(function() {

    var $list = $('#expList'),
        $listItem = $list.find('ul li'),
        $listItemChildren = $listItem.children('ul');

    function prepareList() {            
        $listItemChildren.hide();
        $listItem.addClass('collapsed');
        $listItem.on('click', onListItemClick);
    };

    function onListItemClick(event) {
        $this = $(this);
        if (this == event.target) {
            $this.toggleClass('expanded');
            $this.children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        return false;
    };

    prepareList();

});
```

It is good practice to cache selectors like I have done in the first few lines of the closure. If you are still having problems, log `$listItem` and make sure that it contains an array containing the 4 list items you expect. If the selection is correct, add a log inside of the `onListItemClick` callback and log out what `this` is etc. etc.

Comment: It is not working. And I do not know how to use log. I am new to javascript

Comment: Personally I use Chrome for debugging, so my advice will assume the use of this browser. Navigate to `View > Developer > Developer Tools` or press `ALT + CMD + I`. This should open up the developer tools panel. From there you should see a series of tabs along the top. Click on the **Console**. This is where your JavaScript warnings, errors and logs will appear. To log something in the console you write `console.log('Hello World');` – you can test this by writing this directly in the console, since it is interactive. To log your selection, paste `console.log($listItem);` below its declaration.